# Is there a way to pass arrays of different types to an interface implementation

Tags: c#, arrays, interface

So I have the following scenario:

I'm writing a program which accepts content in arrays of various types (string, byte, etc.), parses that content into a data structure, and then stores the structured data somewhere. Since the parsing methods can be pretty different, depending upon which type of data is received, I wanted to define separate file parsing classes, but define methods and properties that they should all implement. I wanted to use an interface for this, but I can't figure out how to tell the interface that its ParseFile method, for example, is going to accept some type of array as an input parameter. If I write something like the following in an interface:

```
void ParseFile(Array[] fileContents);
```

And then try to implement that method in a ByteParser class, like so:

```
public void ParseFile(Byte[] fileContents){
//Do whatever
}
```

I get a compiler error, that my implementing class doesn't implement the ParseFile method. I'm thinking that's because the compiler doesn't cast by default, and even though ByteArray is a derivative of Array, it's not of type Array.

Is there any way to do what I'm trying to do here, force the interface to accept any type of array and allow my implementing classes to handle it from there?

Comment: Generally speaking, avoid exposing or accepting .NET arrays because they lack guards over mutability and they have weird contravariant behaviour. Instead you should use `IReadOnlyList<T>` or `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` when accepting data (or `IEnumerable<T>` if you don't care about the length) and only return an array when you know you need to.

Comment: This can be done with generics: `T[]` (although usually better to use an interface as appropriate, which will still require generics here with the desired design, and promoted through).

Comment: "which accepts content in arrays of various types (string, byte, etc.), parses that content into a data structure" - if that data is already passed-in as `String[]` or `Byte[]` then presumably (or strictly-speaking) it's already parsed. What does the `void ParseFile(String[])` method do compared to the `void ParseFile(Byte[])` method?

Comment: "and even though ByteArray is a derivative of Array, it's not of type Array." - you have a LOT to learn about the CLR's handling of arrays, methinks.

Comment: "Is there any way to do what I'm trying to do here, force the interface to accept any type of array and allow my implementing classes to handle it from there?" - I think this is an "X/Y Problem" - I think you've got started on the wrong idea in the first place (having multiple input array types)  which has led you do new questions which you don't need to ask in the first place - **please post details of the original problem you're trying to solve**.

Comment: If the interface is `interface IFoo { void ParseFile(Array fileContents);` then what happens if the implementation is `void ParseFile(Byte[]);` and the caller passes-in a `String[]`?

Comment: `Array[]` is wrong. If you're using arrays (rather than generics) then it should be just `Array`. You aren't accepting an array-of-`Array` objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current idea (of using `Array` (**not** `Array[]`) and `Byte[]`) is... ill-informed and ill-advised.

For one, .NET requires implementations of an interface to **exactly match** the interface definition, so if you have a method `void ParseFile(Array fileContents)` then the implementation **must** also have `void ParseFile(Array fileContents)` - you cannot have `ParseFile(Byte[] fileContents)`. Here's why you can't:

Supposing that this actually compiles:

```
interface IFileBuilder {
    void ParseFile(Array fileContents);
}

class OctetFileBuilder : IFileBuilder {
    public void ParseFile(Byte[] fileContents) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

...then run this:

```
void Main() {
    
    Byte[]   byteArray = new Byte[] { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05 };
    String[] strArray  = new String[] { "foo", "bar", "baz" };

    OctetFileBuilder ofb = new OctetFileBuilder();
    ofb.ParseFile( byteArray ); // OK, so far so good.

    ofb.ParseFile( strArray ); // Compiler rejects this because `String[]` isn't `Byte[]`. That's also OK.

    IFileBuilder fb = ofb;
    fb.ParseFile( byteArray ); // This would be okay because a `Byte[]` can be the argument for an `Array` parameter.

    fb.ParseFile( strArray ); // But what happens here?
    
}
```

That last line there is the problem: `fb.ParseFile( strArray )`.

The implementation expects `Byte[]` but it's being passed a `String[]`.

I imagine you would expect .NET to throw a runtime error - or that it would somehow magically know how to convert `String[]` to `Byte[]` (no, it won't). Instead that entire program simply won't compile.

Now, in reality, your implementation would have to look like this in order for it to build:

```
class OctetFileBuilder : IFileBuilder {
    public void ParseFile(Array fileContents) {
        Byte[] byteArray = (Byte[])fileContents; // Runtime cast.
    }
}
```

...so now your code will compile and start to run, but it  will crash before it can complete because when `ParseFile` is given a `String[]` it will cause an `InvalidCastException` because you can't meaningfully directly cast from `String[]` to `Byte[]`.

#### Solution: Covariant generics!

This is what generic types (and contravariance and covariance) are all about and why when designing polymorphic interfaces you need to think carefully about the *direction* of the movement of data inside your program (as generally speaking, "forward"/"input" data can be "shrunk" and "output" data can be "grown"/"expanded"/"extended" - but not vice-versa. This is what the `in` and `out` generic-type modifiers are for.

So I'd do it like this: <sub>(disclaimer: I have no idea what your interface is actually for, nor why you would want anything other than `Byte[]` for your `ParseFile` method parameter...)</sub>

```
interface IFileBuilder<in TInput>
{
    void ParseFile( IReadOnlyList<TInput> fileContents )
}

class OctetFileBuilder : IFileBuilder<Byte> {
    public void ParseFile(Byte[] fileContents) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

(Note that *in this particular case* the use of contravariance/covariance modifiers (the `in TInput` part) is pointless because the primitive and base-types in .NET (`Byte`, `Int32`, `String`, etc) are either structs without inheritance or are sealed-types).

Usage:

```
void Main() {
    
    Byte[]   byteArray = new Byte[] { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05 };
    String[] strArray  = new String[] { "foo", "bar", "baz" };

    OctetFileBuilder ofb = new OctetFileBuilder();
    ofb.ParseFile( byteArray ); // OK, so far so good.

    ofb.ParseFile( strArray ); // Compiler rejects this because `String[]` isn't `Byte[]`. That's also OK.

    IFileBuilder<Byte> fb = ofb;
    fb.ParseFile( byteArray ); // OK

    fb.ParseFile( strArray ); // Compiler error: `String[]` is not `IReadOnlyList<Byte>`.
    
}
```

So your hypothetical runtime error is now a guaranteed compile-time error.

And compile-time errors are much better than runtime errors - and this approach also means you can reason about the direction of data-flow in your application.